# How can I add a CSS editor inside my HTML page

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I'm creating a web page where user can add their custom CSS. As of now I'm using plain text area but it is not parsing new lines and css properties properly.
Which is the best way I can create a panel to read and validate CSS inside my HTML page

My current form is like this

```
<div class="form-group" style="min-height: 300px;">
     <label for="cssString" class="control-label col-sm-4">
          Enter CSS
     </label>
     <div class="col-sm-8">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="cssString" name="customCssData" cols="5" rows="15"> `+ customCss + ` </textarea>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried? That way it might be easier for us to understand

Comment: Depending on how much flexibility you want to give to the user, I'd be tempted to use a `<form>`-based UI with radio buttons and select options rather than parsing a plain text area.

Comment: Updated current text area

Comment: @Rounin : User will be just copy pasting CSS. We cant give radio or checkbox as the css properties might be very big.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, can you maybe use a `<textarea>` and a `<button type="button">` such that when the button is clicked, a script creates a new `<style>` element in the `<head>` and adds the contents of the `<textarea>` to the `<style>` element?

Answer (score 2):

### Use a content editable, visible, style tag.

**Note**: This is a partial answer, because I cannot figure out the bug with new styles.

In the example below you can use the content editable style tag, to change 'green' to 'blue' and see the document update. This might be related to stack overflow snippets, but I could not add a new style for the spans to change anything.

```css
style {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1> Heading </h1>

<span> Something else</span>

<pre>
<style contenteditable="true">
  h1 {
    color: green;
  }
</style>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. But how can I submit this via form?